connection to Api through Postman does not work Service Desk Plus
I'm trying to test the API:
<service domain|custom domain>/app//api/v3/requests
Making the respective changes to my service desk would be like this:
https://sdpondemand.manageengine.com/app/itdesk/api/v3/requests/1632
I configured as indicated in the documentation, but I get a 401 error. I don't know if I'm missing something or if I don't have adequate permissions, as they told me the account they gave me has administrator permissions
I generated the token as indicated in the documentation
I would appreciate it if you can help me. I don't know what to do.
enter image description here
I generated the token, I put what was indicated, I was waiting for a response with the request data

Can you update your question and share the API specification\documentation.  You are failing the authentication, so can't be following the instructions fully.
